# environment configuration ('ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command.)

Tags: angular

Unable to run ng serve command. showing error

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Settings I have added in Environment Variable is

#### User Variable for user

```
path : C:\Users\aprajita.singh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
```

#### System Variable

```
path : C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\%M2_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin
```

I have added some maven configuration of the backend communication.

Kindly tell me what is the exact procedure of setting the node path.

Comment: Looks like angular and or node environment is getting bad. Nothing related to Maven

Comment: did you install it globally?

Comment: Yeah, I have run the command npm install -g @angular/cli. Still not able to fix it

Comment: Looks like angular and or node environment is getting bad.   How to resolve this. NitiSingh

Comment: Is there any way to get rid out of this issue. I am totally stuck over here.

Answer (score 1):

If npm command woorks on your cmd then you can follow the following steps.

## At first You Can Install Node Then Install Angular:

- To download [click here](https://nodejs.org/en/) or visit https://nodejs.org/en/
- Then open cmd and try the command given bellow

  - `npm install -g @angular/cli`

### If npm not found or not recognized then you can follow the following steps:

- Search *environment variables* from start menu's search box.
- Click it then go to *Environment Variables*
- Click **PATH**
- click **Edit**
- Click **New** and try to *copy* and *paste* your path for '*bin*' folder [find where you installed the node] for example according to my machine '`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin`'

#### If you got any error. try the another step:

- Click **New**, then browse for the '*bin*' folder

> If you got any error still now, please take a screen shot and post with description as needed.

If `npm --info` command works. Then please shut down your PC for 5 minutes. And  install angular by hitting following commands on cmd.

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` (if it is installed before) Then `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and restart your PC.